# Handling form data in PreactJS

Tags: forms, preact

I am porting a react app to preact. Handling data from a form on submit throws a `TypeError: this.createIssue is not a function at Object.createTestIssue [as click]` error.

The code is a follows:

```
class IssueList extends Component {
  state = { issues: [] };

  createIssue(newIssue) {
    const updatedIssues = this.state.issues.slice();
    newIssue.id = this.state.issues.length + 1;
    updatedIssues.push(newIssue);
    this.setState({ issues: updatedIssues });
  }

  createTestIssue() {
    const issue = {
      status: 'New',
      owner: 'Pieta',
      created: new Date(),
      title: 'Completion date should be optional'
    };
    this.createIssue(issue);
  }

  render(props, state) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Issue Tracker</h1>
        <IssueFilter />
        <hr />
        <IssueTable issues={state.issues} />
        <hr />
        <IssueAdd createIssue={this.createIssue} />
        <hr />
        <button onClick={this.createTestIssue}>Add Test</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default IssueList;
```

I have tried to create a constructor and setting the state from inside the constructor, however there is a `ReferenceError: state is not defined at new IssueList`.

I have looked at `linkState` module that preact recommends for forms, however, I have not been able to set it up correctly. Do I pass an empty object and an object with the data that I want to be added to my array; something like:

```
render({}, { state }) {
  ...
}
```

But that does not allow me to access the state. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `preact-compat`? Might make the process easier, as it allows you to use react apis in preact.

Comment: I am using `"preact-compat": "^3.18.4"`. Replacing the entire code that works in React, I now get `Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined at IssueList.createIssue at IssueList.createTestIssue at HTMLButtonElement.eventProxy`.

Comment: Did you see my answer? I think your destructuring incorrectly

Comment: Yes, I have de-structuring `render({}, { key, value }) { ... }` like you suggested. I still get the `TypeError: this.createIssue is not a function at Object.createTestIssue [as click]` when I click the `Add Test` button. What am I missing that does not allow me to access to the function?

Answer (score 0):

In preact props and state are passed into the render function, as you have shown.

```
render(props, state) {
  ...
}
```

This allows you to use [destructuring#MOZDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to

```
render({}, { state }) {
  ...
}
```

What you have ^^ would not be beneficial, and might hide state behind another object. What you should have is:

```
render({}, { ...state }) {
  ...
}
```

OR in my opinion the best solution assuming `state = {key: 'test', value: 1}`:

```
render({}, { key, value }) {
  ...
}
```

If you do not wish to use anything from props you can either use the empty object as shown above or just have `props`, but then not use it.